# How transpose collection in a lodash way?

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I do have a collection like this:

```
{
    a: {
        x: 1,
        y: 2,
    },
    b: {
        x: 3,
        y: 4,
    }
}
```

And I want to transpose like this:

```
{
    x: {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
    },
    y: {
        a: 3,
        b: 4,
    }
}
```

Today i'm using

```
var result = {};
for (var c in value)
  for (var r in value[c]) 
    result[r][c] = value[c][r];
return result;
```

But what is the "lodash way" to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_.forOwn` if you really want to use Lodash:

```js
const value = {a:{x:1,y:2},b:{x:3,y:4}};
let result = {};
_.forOwn(value, (v, c) => _.forOwn(v, (w, r) => (result[r] = result[r] || {})[c] = w));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```